# Converting / Rounding a number to the closest match within a range where they all offset by 30 by getting its upperbound and lowerbound values?

Tags: c#, numbers, int, matching

First of all, I'm not really sure if I have framed my question correctly, but what I'm looking for can be better explained by looking at the below visual representation:

I have a method which returns an `int` within the range of `0` and `360`.

Now, for further manipulation, I would like to `round?` or get the closest match from the numbers which are offset by 30. So how can I achieve this. Also, is there a `specific term` for the function that I'm looking for?

You may also edit the question if you think it can be written better.

Best Regards,
Navik.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for any list where the items are an equal distance apart (i.e. 30, 60, 90).

**EDIT**

I've updated the code to use AlexD's elegant solution so that it will work with lists of any 'step' value, and with any starting (or ending) value (i.e. it could start with a negative number, like: `-20, -15, -10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20`):

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the value of the item in the list of
/// numbers that is closest to the given number
/// </summary>
/// <param name="number">Any number</param>
/// <param name="numbers">A list of numbers, sorted from lowest to highest,
/// where the difference between each item is the same</param>
/// <returns>The value of the list item closest to the given number</returns>
public static int GetClosestNumber(int number, List<int> numbers)
{
    if (numbers == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("numbers");
    if (numbers.Count == 0)
        throw new
            ArgumentException("There are no items to compare against.", "numbers");
    if (numbers.Count == 1) return numbers[0]; // Short-circuit for single-item lists

    var step = Math.Abs(numbers[1] - numbers[0]);

    // Get closest number using a slight modification of AlexD's elegant solution
    var closestNumber = (Math.Abs(number) + (step / 2)) / step * 
        step * (number < 0 ? -1 : 1);

    // Ensure numbers is within min/max bounds of the list
    return Math.Min(Math.Max(closestNumber, numbers[0]), numbers[numbers.Count - 1]);
}
```

Comment: Hello Rufus, first of all, thank you for answering the question. I won't be able to give it a go at the moment but I will soon try your suggestion. Also, when you say any list, does it mean - if my offset changed from 30 to 6 and the range became `6, 12, 18...354, 360`. Would it still work?

Comment: Also, if you could reconstruct my question being able to understand what I need, that'd be great!

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean (if you pass in a list of numbers like `0, 6, 12, 18`, and you pass in `8` it will return `6`, and if you pass in '9' it will return '12'.

Comment: @NavikGoswami I updated the code to work with any step value and any beginning/ending value, using a modified version of AlexD's solution. I also added an xml summary, describing what it does. Hopefully this answers your question?